# SQL Pivot with similar records

Tags: sql, pivot

Hy,

I have the following table:

```
Job-------|-Segment--|--Days

Analyst---|--F-------|--34

Analyst---|--F-------|--25

Worker----|--Z-------|--32
```

And I need it like this:

```
Job-------|--F-----|--Z---

Analyst---|--34----|------

Analyst---|--25----|------

Worker----|--------|--32--
```

Do you guys have any idea how I can achieve that, preferably with a PIVOT, if possible.

Thank you all in advance

Answer (score 2):

Will it work for you ?

```
select job,
case segment 
when 'F' then [days] 
end
AS [F],

case segment 
when 'Z' then [days] 
end
AS [Z]
from your_table
```